# Get request with dates as parameter Angular 8 (ts) + .NET Core

Tags: angular, .net-core, angular-material, httprequest

I tried sending 2 dates as a parameter in the get request but I am getting only this:

[image: C#]

[image: Angular]

Model

```
    public class Dates
{
    public DateTime from { get; set; }
    public DateTime to { get; set; }
}
```

.net core

```
 [HttpGet]
    [Route("main/exportToExcel")]
    public string ExportToExcel([FromQuery] Dates dates)
    {}
```

Html

```
  <p>
    <mat-form-field color="accent" appearance="fill">
      <mat-label>Data od</mat-label>
      <input formControlName="from" matInput [matDatepicker]="picker1">
      <mat-datepicker-toggle matSuffix [for]="picker1"></mat-datepicker-toggle>
      <mat-datepicker #picker1></mat-datepicker>
    </mat-form-field>

  </p>

  <p>
    <mat-form-field color="accent" appearance="fill">
      <mat-label>Data do</mat-label>
      <input formControlName="to" matInput [matDatepicker]="picker2">
      <mat-datepicker-toggle matSuffix [for]="picker2"></mat-datepicker-toggle>
      <mat-datepicker #picker2></mat-datepicker>
    </mat-form-field>

  </p>
</form>
```

Angular

```
 let params = new HttpParams();
  params = params.append('from', this.datepipe.transform(this.addNewItemForm.get('from').value, 'yyyy-mm-dd'));
  params = params.append('to', this.datepipe.transform(this.addNewItemForm.get('to').value, 'yyyy-mm-dd'));
  console.log(params);

  this.http.get(this.baseURL + "main/exportToExcel/", { params })
    .subscribe(event => {
```

Is this correct way to do this?

Comment: Hi @Xia,It seems you do not get the correct date right?What did you use in asp.net core,angular or angular.js?

Comment: Hi yes I updated the question. Sorry :)

Comment: Hi @Xia,did `console.log(params)` log the correct date?

Comment: Yes. I added a second photo where it can be seen :/

Comment: If i hard-coded and pass a date like "2019-8-4",it works well.How did you do for `this.addNewItemForm.get('to').value`?Could you please share more code?

Comment: I updated my answer. Passing the date as a string works but I am still wondering how I can send these dates in datetime format.

Comment: Hi @Xia, the string parameter will be posted to the backend and automatically converted to Datetime.But the datetime must be valid.2021-00-01 is not a valid date.Just to think,there is no month called 0.

Comment: Ah ok... so I have a problem with converting the dates. thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, so bad formatting was the problem.

```
  import * as moment from 'moment';

  var momentVariable = moment(this.addNewItemForm.get('from').value, 'MM-DD-YYYY');
  var from = momentVariable.format('YYYY-MM-DD');

  var momentVariable = moment(this.addNewItemForm.get('to').value, 'MM-DD-YYYY');
  var to = momentVariable.format('YYYY-MM-DD');


  let params = new HttpParams();
  params = params.append('from', from);
  params = params.append('to', to);


 this.http.get(this.baseURL + "main/exportToExcel/", { params, responseType: 'text' })
  .pipe(map((data: string) => data),
    catchError(this.errorHandler)
  );
```

c#

```
    [HttpGet]
    [Route("main/exportToExcel")]
    public string ExportToExcel([FromQuery] Dates dates)
    {
```

Answer (score 1):

You can easily use JavaScript `toISOString()` method like this:

`let date = new Date(this.form.value.date).toISOString();`

this will give you the date as a timestamp which you can then send to your API

but first, you need to set formControlNname correctly and then send the value